# Socket.io Javascript emit to Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, socket.io

I have this Javascript socket.io emit function and I need to write it in Swift, SwiftUI with those instructions from a documentation:

**To subscribe and get archiving process events:**

1. subscribe to 'galleryArchive' socket event
2. emit via socket:
   socket.emit("subscribeOnGalleryArchiveInfo", { archiveEventName, galleryId }, data => {});

The script:

```
socketClient.emit(
    'subscribeOnGalleryArchiveInfo',
    { archiveEventName: eventName, galleryId },
    (event: GalleryArchiveEvent) => {
        const { data } = event;
        setArchivingData(data);
    }
);
```

All I did is initialized the Socket viewModel in Swift, but can't seem to recreate this emit function without bunch of errors.

My Code:

```
class GalleryArchiveSocket: ObservableObject {
    @Published var archiveEventName: String
    @Published var galleryId: String

    var manager: SocketManager?
    var socket: SocketIOClient?

    init(archiveEventName: String, galleryId: String) {
        self.archiveEventName = archiveEventName
        self.galleryId = galleryId
        guard let apiUrl = AppConfig.rootURL
        else {
            return
        }
        manager = SocketManager(
            socketURL: apiUrl,
            config: [
                .extraHeaders(
                    [
                        HTTPHeader.authorization.key: HTTPHeader.authorization.value.headerValue
                    ]
                ),
                .log(true),
                .compress
            ]
        )
        guard let socket = manager?.defaultSocket
        else {
            return
        }
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {_, _ in
            print("I'm connected")
            // Emit function with param ? and receive data ?
        }
        socket.connect()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could use this to emit:  
`socket.emit("subscribeOnGalleryArchiveInfo", yourdata)`

and to receive, use this: `socket.on("SomeMessage") { data, ack in  ....}`

Comment: @workingdog and how do you think the syntax of "your data" will look like If I'll match it with the Javascript ? sorry if its obvious but no experience with Sockets

Comment: @workingdog I was able to solve it, and found how to pass the data correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution with looking into a lot of Socket.io swift examples until I saw someone passes the data like: `["archiveEventName": self.archiveEventName, "galleryId": self.galleryId]`

and [@workingdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11969817/workingdog) helped with the initial syntax.

```
socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {_, _ in
            socket.emit("subscribeOnGalleryArchiveInfo", ["archiveEventName": self.archiveEventName, "galleryId": self.galleryId])
            socket.on("GalleryArchiveEvent") { data, ack in
                print(data)
            }
        }
```